# How to extract information about each constituent 'wave' of a signal?

Tags: frequency, cross-correlation, correlation

I have a vector containing wind speeds sampled at 1Hz over ten minutes.

I have applied a lowpass filter of 0.25Hz to get only the wind speeds I am interested in.

I now want to use MATLAB to identify information on all of the 'waves' which combine to form the complete ten minute wind speed profile. I'd like to know the waves' minimum wind speed, mean wind speed and frequency/time period.

I have tried using cross-correlation, however I couldn't get this to show me whether any of the test waves I'd applied were found in the original signal.

I will attach a figure containing filtered wind speed (600s), the 'test wave' of duration 9 seconds, and the result of the cross-correlation. Any test wave used results in same output of cross-correlation whereas id like to input various test waves and find out if they are present in the original signal. Maybe resampling?[image]

Comment: it is still not clear what you are looking for. can u please attach a signal figure? what is a "wave"?

Comment: I have updated the original post please see

Comment: still not clear what is a wave

Comment: Hi Max. So you have a set of "test" signals, like the one in Fig. 1(b) and you want to check whether they are present in the wind speed signal you have plotted in Fig. 1(a). Is that true?

Comment: yes thats correct, i have over 100 test signals, i have got them so theyre now sampled at 20hz, the original signal is sampled at 1hz